# Refreshing Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have bounded Gridview through Wizard. It's working fine. but i want that if i add new data it should be visible in the gridview. But gridview not refreshing. I know i can perform this programmatically . but i want to do it in this case also.

Any help will be appreciated.
thanks

Answer (score 2):

in the action method of the Save button of your add from data, add this

```
dataGridView.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the GridView within an UpdatePanel and setting the GridView to AutoPostBack="true". set the UpdatePanel trigger to the ID of the add button you use to add new data to the gridview

```
<asp:UpdatePanel>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Gridview ID="grid" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <button id="btnID" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#splitModal" style="width:115px;">Split Record</button>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnID" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```